# How to bind ComboBox to a list in JavaFX?

Tags: list, javafx, combobox, bind

My application periodically adds Strings to a **List** using a Thread. I want to add those strings to a **ComboBox** as soon as they get added to the **List**. Is there anyway to bind a **ComboBox** to a **List**?

My Code:

```
static final int max = 20;
List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();

public void getIP() throws UnknownHostException {

    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws UnknownHostException {
            InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
            for (int i = 10; i <= max; i++) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    ip[3] = (byte) i;
                    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);

                    if (address.isReachable(100)) {
     //============================== Populating List ===============//
                        ips.add(address.getHostName());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
                updateProgress(i, max);

            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    //============================== Bind ComboBox to List Code here ===============//
    indicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to bind a simple list, since it's not observable. Even with a `ObservableList`, there would be the problem of the updates coming from a different thread.

You could however use a synchronized list and use the value property to pass the current size, which would allow you to add the items via listener.

**Example**

This uses a `ListView` instead of a `ComboBox`, since the results are visible without user interaction, but you could also use `targetList = comboBox.getItems()`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    List<String> targetList = listView.getItems();
    final List<String> ips = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            Random random = new Random();
            int size;
            for (size = 0; size < 100; size++) {
                ips.add(Integer.toString(size));
                updateValue(size);
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(500));
            }

            return size;
        }

    };
    task.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // add values not yet in the target list.
        for (int i = targetList.size(), newSize = newValue; i < newSize; i++) {
            targetList.add(ips.get(i));
        }
    });

    new Thread(task).start();

    Scene scene = new Scene(listView);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

It would be a bit simpler though to simply post the updates on the ui thread using `Platform.runLater` though:

```
ips = comboBox.getItems();

Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
        for (int i = 10; i <= max; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                ip[3] = (byte) i;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);

                if (address.isReachable(100)) {
 //============================== Populating List ===============//
                    final String hostName = address.getHostName();
                    // do update on application thread
                    Platform.runLater(() -> ips.add(hostName));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            updateProgress(i, max);

        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: I used Platform.runLater and it works. However I'm having a weird problem, if I have the ComboBox opened while I'm populating it, it displays only one visible item at a time and adds the others to a scrolldown. However, if I open the ComboBox after my thread is finished it displays all items just fine without a  scrolldown.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to do the following:

change

```
List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
final ObservableList<String> ips = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

change:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>()
```

to

```
Task<ObservableList<String> task = new Task<>(){
@Override
public ObservableList<String> call() throws UnknownHostException {
...
return ips;  
}
};
comboBox.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
```